Vue to Laravel page redirect is not working in Vite.js
I am using laravel 11 with vue3,
When I am trying to redirect from Vue page to a Blade page then it's not working,
I mentioned /profile route in web.php like this:
Route::get('/profile', [UserController::class, 'index'])->name('profile');

and after that I have my vue routes like this:
Route::get('/vue/{any}', function () {
    return view('app');
})->where('any', '.*');

Note: My app Vue Routes has Vue as prefix in it but when I am redirecting on profile page from a vue page then it's not working:
https://domain.test/https://domain.test/profile
It's add the domain url in the start which is wired, Here is my js code even I used hardcoded redirection:
window.location.href = 'https://domain.test/profile';


This question is similar to: Difference between window.location and location.href. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

So to redirect to another domain, change the value of window.location
